# No EjbContext available

Tags: java, jboss, xhtml, ejb

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 to develop simple EJB application with external database (Postgres).

I want to find out currently logged user's username inside a Bean.
I'm getting this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: JBAS014558: No EjbContext available as no EJB invocation is active
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

root cause:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS014558: No EjbContext available as no EJB invocation is active [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014558: No EjbContext available as no EJB invocation is active]
org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:135)
org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:74)
org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:123)
org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
com.FantasyGame.DataProviderBean.getForests(DataProviderBean.java:130)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:735)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:246)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

when trying to access context:

```
@Singleton
@ManagedBean(name = "dataProviderBean")public class DataProviderBean {
//...
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    EJBContext sessionContext = (SessionContext)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
```

I'm accessing dataProviderBean from .xhtml page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{dataProviderBean.getForests()}" var="category">
```

I thought adding jndi.properties file with configuration would help, but it still didn't work. I'm beginner and don't know what I'm missing. Do you have an idea what is causing the problem? I'd be glad to provide any more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace?  How are you acquiring an instance of DataProviderBean?

Comment: What `@Singleton` annotation is it? From CDI or EJB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I made this work.
Probably, just like @Szarpul mentioned, EJBContext cannot be obtained from ManagedBean. Thus I've created another class to provide context:

```
@Stateless
public class ContextProviderBean {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sctx;

    public void setSctx(SessionContext sctx) {
        this.sctx = sctx;
    }

    public SessionContext getSctx() {
        return sctx;
    }

}
```

and added it to my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dataProviderBean")
public class DataProviderBean {
    @EJB
    private ContextProviderBean ctxProvider;

    public DataProviderBean() {
        super();
        ctxProvider = new ContextProviderBean();
    }
//...
}
```

This way I can access context anywhere in DataProviderBean:

```
EJBContext sessionContext = ctxProvider.getSctx();
String currentUser = sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
```

Comment: You don't have to initiate your EJB bean with 'ctxProvider = new ContextProviderBean();' as it should be injected by the container. What is more, as mentioned earlier, rather than exposing EJBContext to MahagedBean, you should create business method inside EJB bean that would return CallerPrincipal name.

Comment: What you did works indeed. The core issue was that you can't combine `@Stateless` with `@ManagedBean`. You CAN combine `@Stateless` and `@Named`. You should not use `@ManagedBean` anyway, it's an effectively deprecated annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get `EJBContext` from `ManagedBean`. You should be obtaining `EJBContext` from inside of the EJB bean. [Here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html) is tutorial how to get `EJBContext`.

Comment: I tried making another EJB class (not ManagedBean), just to provide EJBContext, and import it in current Bean. It didn't work. Also thank you for the link, but I have already studied that page for a while before posting my question with no positive results.

Comment: What you mean by 'It didn't work'? By saying 'tried making another EJB class' do you mean that you have created business interface through which you injected your EJB bean in managed bean (this is the way how you should obtain ejb bean)? Moreover, for what purpose you need EJBContext to use outside of the EJB bean?