# How to inject security context into CDI Named Bean

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, cdi

How to inject security context into CDI `@Named` bean?

I need to perform some custom validations, like dynamic role names validation, so I need to inject `SessionContext`. This is done with this:

```java
@Resource
javax.ejb.SessionContext context;
```

But this injection **only works** in EJB beans, so I need to create an `@Stateless` bean just to wrap `SessionContext`, then I can inject this stateless bean into named bean and use it to access the security context.

I have tried with `@Inject javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext` also, but this do not work at all.

**Obs.** If there is another approach, this will be welcome too!

---

Environment:

- Wildfly 24
- Java SE 11

References

- [No EjbContext available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317955/no-ejbcontext-available)
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-8-security

Comment: Have you tried to inject with `@Resource`, just like in EJBs? If I remember correctly, `@Resource` works for CDI when executed in a JEE application server, might be mistaken though (or may not work for all kinds of resources)!

Comment: Also I have written a few things things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66750926/2764255) that I think apply to your case as well.

Comment: Yes, I tried @NikosParaskevopoulos it. See this comment in question: "But this injection only works in EJB beans". Only works on EJB, on Named fails.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for in the security context? You _can't_ inject an Ejb Context... because it's CDI :) Maybe we can find something else that would work instead

Comment: Hi @JonathanS.Fisher. Yes, I can inject a Stateless EJB bean into a Named bean, tested and confirmed. CDI have some conflicts on this, maybe with Jakarta EE this can be resolved.

Comment: What specifically are you using in the Security Context?

Comment: Try to make you class "managed" by the container by adding a `@javax.annotation.ManagedBean' annotation on your class